# ¿Cómo copio un contenido concreto de una rama de Git a otra?

Tags: git

Pongamos que tengo creadas dos ramas (a parte de la principal), las llamaré *rama-a* y *rama-b*.

Voy haciendo commits en ambas ramas y en un momento dado quiero traspasar los cambios de un commit de la *rama-a* a la *rama-b*, cambios que afectan a un fichero concreto, ¿cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> quiero traspasar los cambios de un commit de la rama-a a la rama-b

Si realmente se trata de un solo commit que deseas pasar a la otra rama, entonces puedes usar [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) .

Por ejemplo, si deseas tomar el contenido del commit `abc123` de la rama `rama-a` y aplicarla a la `rama-b`, usarías los comandos siguientes:

```
git checkout rama-b
git cherry-pick abc123
```

Comment: Supongo que el *commit* queda en el lugar del histórico de la rama a la que se traspasa que le corresponde en el tiempo, por ejemplo ¿si el *commit* que añado es anterior a la creación de la rama, quedaría como el primer *commit*? y en este caso, ¿sería como si la rama hubiera sido creada en un momento previo una vez hecha la incorporación?

Comment: no. en realidad no transfiere el commit, sino que crea un nuevo commit con cambios equivalentes. De modo que el nuevo commit queda como el mas reciente.